# New Apple Vision API VNTranslationalImageRegistrationRequest

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, apple-vision

I am trying to play with the [Image Alignment Analysis](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) part of the new Vision API but i am struggling with the initialisation of VNTranslationalImageRegistrationRequest. My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Vision

class ImageTranslation {

    var sourceImage: UIImage!

    lazy var imageTranslationRequest: VNTranslationalImageRegistrationRequest = {
//This line fails        let translationRequest = VNTranslationalImageRegistrationRequest(targetedCGImage: sourceImage.cgImage, completionHandler: self.handleImageTranslationRequest)

        return translationRequest
    }()

    func handleImageTranslationRequest(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {

        guard let observations = request.results as? [VNImageTranslationAlignmentObservation]
            else { print("unexpected result type from VNDetectRectanglesRequest")
                return
        }
        guard observations.first != nil else {
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            observations.forEach { observation in
                let transform = observation.alignmentTransform
                print(transform)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But on the marked line above i keep getting the following error and am unsure how to fix it. `Instance member 'sourceImage' cannot be used on type 'ImageTranslation'`

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

An example how to use [VNTranslationalImageRegistrationRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vntranslationalimageregistrationrequest) on two images to compute the translation between the two images:

```
import UIKit
import Vision

class ImageTranslation {

    func translateImages(for referenceImage: UIImage,
                         floatingImage: UIImage,
                         completion: @escaping (_ alignmentTransform : CGAffineTransform?) -> Void) {
        let translationRequest = VNTranslationalImageRegistrationRequest(targetedCGImage: floatingImage.cgImage!) { (request: VNRequest, error: Error?) in
            completion((request.results?.first as? VNImageTranslationAlignmentObservation)?.alignmentTransform)
        }
        let vnImage = VNSequenceRequestHandler()
        try? vnImage.perform([translationRequest], on: referenceImage.cgImage!)
    }

}
```